# Can 'to get' be used as 'to have'

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I've been learning English with the Friends TV show and in one of the episodes Monica says about a 'slumber' party and what they have for it - cookies dough, twister, trashy magazines. I was wondering why she says it using 'to get' like '*We got some trashy magazines, we got cookie dough, we got Twister.*'? Is it maybe another way of saying 'have got', so she could mean - '*We've got trashy magazines etc.*'?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some dialect of English (especially American)

"We got" is understood to mean the same as "We've got" meaning "We have obtained (and no possess)"

So "We got cookies" is a fairly casual and particularly American way  of saying "We've got cookies" which has a very similar meaning to "We have cookies".

If you got something it strongly suggests that now you have it.  Even in formal English "We received your package yesterday" implies that "We have you your package".

Comment: Thank you! That helped :)